# Search an item in the listbox where the item to be searched is in textbox and no button click C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listbox, windows-forms-designer

say ive a listbox with items already present, say the items are

```
Ant
Adam    
Ball
Cat
Dog
Ear
Frog
```

above the listbox there is a textbox prompting the user to search

say if i enter in textbox **ad** then it must point to Adam if i remove **a** then it must point to Dog
and must not use a button to search

also if i click on the item **cat** in the listbox, then next to the listbox there is a textbox it says **Hi I'm Cat**

I see that its not correct to use textbox to display **Hi I'm Cat** what shall i use to display info regarding the details of selected item.

***Found solution myself***

```
    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int index = listBox1.FindString(textBox1.Text, -1);
        if (index != -1)
        {
            listBox1.SetSelected(index, true);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Found solution my self



        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int index = listBox1.FindString(textBox1.Text, -1);
            if (index != -1)
            {
                listBox1.SetSelected(index, true);
            }
        }

Answer (score 1):

you need to update your listbox on the "`TextChanged`" event of TextBox.

get the text written in the textbox inside this event, iterate over the items of listbox and do `Text.Contains`

```
protected void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var current = TextBox1.Text;
            foreach (ListItem item in ListBox1.Items)
            {
                if (item.Text.ToLower().Contains(current.ToLower()))
                    item.Selected = true;
            }
        }
```

this is how you can grab the selected item of listbox:

```
protected void ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(ListBox1.SelectedItem!=null)
            {
               Label1.Text =  ListBox1.SelectedItem.Text;
               //or you can dynamically create a label and add it to the page
               Label lbl = new Label();
               lbl.Text=ListBox1.SelectedItem.Text;
               MyContainer.Controls.Add(lbl);
               //where MyContainer is any server side container, HtmlContainerControl  
               //or HtmlControl 
            }
        }
```

Comment: u need to add using System.Web.UI.WebControls; to your page

Comment: i cant find the namespace. k leave it.

on the click of the listbox item a label with selected item text is to be displayed
how to do that.

Comment: there is an even "SelectedIndexChanged" for ListBox, you can use that to perform any extra logic you want to. i am updating my answer

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be a listbox? If you use a ComboBox instead, you can use the AutoComplete feature. Set AutoCompleteMode to 'SuggestAppend' and AutoCompleteSource to 'ListItems' for example. A listbox does not have that functionality built in, so you would have to implement it yourself.

Also, for the label or textbox next to it to say, "Hi, I'm Cat".. or whatever.. use the SelectedIndexChanged event. In there you can do something like this:

`myLabel.Text = "Hi, I'm " + myComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString()`